# How can I design a multi-column subreport with a single-column header?

Tags: crystal-reports

This one has stumped me all day. I have a subreport with five groups. The outer group needs to be full-width because it serves as a header to repeat on each page (because subreports don't have a page header section). The inner groups need to be multi-column. If I set the Detail to multi-column and make groups multi-column on the Layout, it applies to all groups so I can't have a full-width header on each page.

I'm using Crystal 8.5, but I don't think that will make a difference in terms of a solution. Any advice?

Comment: I'm certain you'll need to move the header outside the subreport, and then find a way to make it print on every page (but only when you're inside the subreport). I don't have a complete solution in mind, but I'm thinking of a conditionally printed section in the page header, or another section in the group header containing the subreport, setting the header to repeat on each page, and conditionally suppressing the section containing the subreport so it only prints once per group.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly. Merge all the cells in the top row and you can place whatever you wanted to be the header inside that textbox.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by merging the cells in the top row; it sounds like a setting I just haven't come across before. Can you clarify?